# How to write the following sign?

Tags: symbols

I am writing my project work in LaTeX, but I am facing certain difficulties to write the sign (it is similar to hash sign, but not clearly).

Please help me to write this:

[image: T sharp]

Comment: I just noticed you have 5 questions in this site, all of them with answers, whereas you marked none of them as “accepted”. Please, go to your profile and mark the answers which solved your problem as accepted; This link shows how you can do that: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852

Answer (score 15):

Next time you need a symbol definition try the [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) website.  You freehand draw your symbol in the box and the site makes suggestions for the latex code to use.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

The symbol is `\sharp`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$T^\sharp$
\end{document}
```

> [image]