# What is the font for "b" letter?

Tags: fonts

[image]

What is the font for "b" letter?

Comment: Looks like `\flat`.

Comment: How to use this statement?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The first part of this expression would be coded `$f^{\flat} ...$`.

Comment: Thank! It worked, but I see it look like "b" letter.

Comment: It's borrowed from a musical notation, which looks more or less like  a b.

Comment: So... two different new contributors ask about the \sharp and \flat symbols within 3 hours of each other?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485484/how-to-write-the-following-sign

Comment: @James seems only natural ...

Comment: @davidbak:  Nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

 \begin{document}

 \[ f^{\flat}\colon R \longrightarrow R \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico: you're perfectly right. I've updated accordingly.

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwJz8.png

What is the font of the letter look like "X"?

Comment: It is simply the Greek letter `χ` (`\chi`, to be used in math mode).