# What is the command for the Weierstrass p function, ℘?

Tags: symbols

I'd like to write the following equation:

[image: Image of a mathematical equation.]

I don't know which symbol is used for the `P` in the numerator. I have tried `\mathcal{}`, `\mathfrak{}`, and `\mathsrc{}`, but it wasn't any of these.

Could someone also recommend notation to describe the power density vector?

Comment: Always try the Detexify website as described in this question/answer.  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485484

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is  the notation for ‘Weierstraß' elliptic function’, called  ‘Weierstraß P’, and obtained with the command `\wp`.  It is in particular used for the parameterisation of elliptic cubic curves.

Comment: On StackExchange, it's best to [always create a new question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741), instead of adding questions in comments. You may, however, find that [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31418/134641) post answers your question.

Comment: You can increase it slighly with `\mathlarger{\wp}` (from the `relsize` package), or with something like, say, `\text{\Large$\wp$}`.

Comment: @Bernard - Unless one is writing *in german*, it's perfectly ok to write "Weierstrass" rather than "Weierstaß". :-)

Comment: @Mico: Actually, I'd love to have the long s ligatures on my keyboard, but they seem  to be unavailable… ;o)

Comment: Yes, it should be used for the Weierstraß p function, but it's abused by several authors.

Answer (score 3):

As correctly indicated to you by the excellent users @barbara beeton both @Bernard the symbol to use is `\wp`. If I can help you, I have also inserted a code where I have used the clone of Times New Roman both in mathematical mode and in text mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\[D_H=\frac{\wp_{\max}}{P_{\text{rad}}/4\pi r^2}\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, the symbol ℘ for the Weierstrass elliptic function is in Unicode as U+2118.  You can paste it directly into your source with `unicode-math`, of use `\wp`.

With legacy font packages, you can still define ℘ as `\wp` using `newunicodechar` (or `inputenc`).