# A symbol for a Q which looks similar to the Weierstrass P, ℘, given by \wp

Tags: symbols

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493394/what-is-the-command-for-the-weierstrass-p-function-%E2%84%98#:%7E:text=It%20is%20the%20notation%20for,parameterisation%20of%20elliptic%20cubic%20curves.&text=On%20StackExchange%2C%20it%27s%20best%20to,of%20adding%20questions%20in%20comments.) question asks for the LaTeX symbol for the "P" typically used in the [Weierstrass ℘-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_elliptic_function). It concludes to use the command `\wp`.

What can I do to get a similar-looking "Q"? [Detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/) does not seem to help, and as far as I can see looking through the adjacent characters to P in Unicode (see [here](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2118), it is referred to as "Script Capital P"), there is no such Unicode character for Q. ([There is one for R](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+211B), namely "Script Capital R").

So, what should I type? The naïve thing, `\wq`, didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Sandy G.' idea, but avoiding to change all `\mathcal` symbols, I'd borrow just the Q from `dutchcal`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dutchcal@scale}{0.85}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\wq}{\mathord{\mathpalette\wq@\relax}}
\newcommand{\wq@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\wp$}%
  \raisebox{\dimeval{\depth-\dp\z@}}{%
    $\m@th#1\text{\usefont{U}{dutchcal}{m}{n}Q}$%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\wp\wq$

$X_{\wp\wq}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As @egreg mentions, this code will change all the `\mathcal` symbols, which may not be desired.

The `dutchcal` Q is similar, but needs to be lowered to mimic `\wp`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dutchcal}

\newcommand{\wq}{\raisebox{-.5ex}{$\mathcal{Q}$}}

\begin{document}

$\wp\wq$

\end{document}
```

You could also consider `rsfso`. Other font options are [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58098/125871).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[cal=rsfso,calscaled=.94]{mathalpha}

\newcommand{\wq}{\raisebox{-.5ex}{$\mathcal{Q}$}}

\begin{document}

$\wp\wq$

\end{document}
```